# How to sort an int[] only at the indices at which a BitSet of same length is set to true in Java

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

While it is no problem sorting a continuous sub-array in Java, I have not found any information on how to sort an array only at certain (non-continous) indices, specified by another data structure, eg. a `BitSet`.

Specifically, given an array such as

```
int[] x = {5,1,8,6,7,0,2,3,9,4};
```

and a BitSet specifying the positions to be sorted

```
BitSet pos = new BitSet(10);
pos.set(0);
pos.set(2);
pos.set(5);
pos.set(6);
pos.set(9); // i.e. pos = {1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}
```

I would like to sort `x` inline only at the positions at which the mask `pos` is `1` while ignoring the remaining indices, i.e.

```
SortOnIndices(x,pos);
```

Should result in

```
x = {0,1,2,6,7,4,5,3,9,8}
```

Is there any efficient way of archiving this without having to implement a custom sorting solution? Can this be done with JAVA 8 streams?

*Edit: Corrected use of BitSet in the example.*

Comment: How about copying to a new array only the needed elements, sorting that array, and then copying them back?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy That would be the trivial solution, yes. I am trying to minimize the memory footprint for my specific application as these lists could become quite large.

Comment: what a good first question! such a pity you did not get the proper upvotes here. The only thing I had in mind is a dummy "in-place" bubble sort, but thats probably very stupid. I promise to think this more

Comment: `BitSet.valueOf(long[])` does not work the way you are using it.

Comment: My bad. I adopted the question to reflect the correct usage of BitSet.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks! I was thinking about a custom Quicksort to get things started. The main issue with that thought however is how to compute the pivot index as there is no guarantee of the mask being uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `BitSet.valueOf(long[])` doesn’t work the way you’re trying to use it. Each element of the `long[]` array is representing 64 bits rather than a single bit. In fact, turning your `1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1` representation into a `BitSet` was the first challenge:

```
BitSet pos = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { Integer.reverse(0b1010011001)>>>22 });
```

Then, we have the problem that every customizable sorting implementation of the Java API works with objects, which would require boxing and representing the source as array or `List`. The methods provided for primitive types all are fixed to natural order.

Trying to create a `List` of positions or similar, that maps to the source array on the fly would suffer from the non-random access when finding the right array position induced by the bitset. But the `default` implementation of `List.sort` circumvents this by copying the list contents into an array anyway. This even applies to all `Stream` approaches that make the operation look fluent, but create intermediate arrays behind the scenes (and also support a custom `Comparator` only for the boxed values).

So when you want to avoid additional memory allocation, none of the builtin sorting facilities will help. The simplest, efficient and memory saving approach would be

```
BitSet ordered = new BitSet();
pos.stream().forEach(ix -> ordered.set(x[ix]));
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it = ordered.stream().iterator();
pos.stream().forEachOrdered(ix -> x[ix]=it.next());
assert !it.hasNext();
```

But this only works if the source array does not contain negative numbers nor duplicates, like in your example data set.

Lifting these restrictions requires some more efforts and more memory:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = pos.stream().map(ix -> x[ix]).summaryStatistics();
int min = stats.getMin(), max = stats.getMax();
int[] counts = new int[max-min+1];
pos.stream().forEach(ix -> counts[x[ix]-min]++);
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it
  = IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max)
             .flatMap(val -> IntStream.range(0, counts[val-min]).map(ix -> val))
             .iterator();
pos.stream().forEachOrdered(ix -> x[ix]=it.next());
assert !it.hasNext();
```

This variant of counting sort is still O(n), but its memory consumption depends on the difference between the smallest and largest number within the set of numbers to sort. But it’s the best you can get, unless you want to implement your own Quicksort or similar. Or, if the divergence between minimum and maximum is too large, you can resort to let the JRE provided algorithm sort a copy:

```
int[] tmp = pos.stream().map(p -> x[p]).toArray();
Arrays.sort(tmp);
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it = Arrays.stream(tmp).iterator();
pos.stream().forEachOrdered(ix -> x[ix]=it.next());
assert !it.hasNext();
```

You could even use the statistics from the second variant to use the variant needing less memory

```
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it;
IntSummaryStatistics stats = pos.stream().map(ix -> x[ix]).summaryStatistics();
int min = stats.getMin(), max = stats.getMax();
if(max-min < stats.getCount()) {
    int[] counts = new int[max-min+1];
    pos.stream().forEach(ix -> counts[x[ix]-min]++);
    it = IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max)
                  .flatMap(val -> IntStream.range(0, counts[val-min]).map(ix -> val))
                  .iterator();
}
else {
    int[] tmp = pos.stream().map(p -> x[p]).toArray();
    Arrays.sort(tmp);
    it = Arrays.stream(tmp).iterator();
}
pos.stream().forEachOrdered(ix -> x[ix]=it.next());
assert !it.hasNext();
```

Comment: Thank for you providing this highly detailed answer. I was not aware that of the copying mechanism behind the scenes when using the Java API.